# StickyHeader Row is hindering the drop down list view

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, sticky, react-select

I have made my row header, of material UI Table component, sticky using the `stickyHeader` attribute

```
 <Table stickyHeader className={classes.table}></Table>
```

there are two drop-downs displayed above this table, these are implemented using the `ReactSelect` component

```
const DropDown = props => (
    <div className={[props.divClasses, props.error ? 'error-class' : ''].join(' ')}>
        <ReactSelect
            {...props}
            classNamePrefix="normal-select"
            disabled={props.disabled ? props.disabled : false}
            multi={props.multi}
            placeholder={props.placeholder ? props.placeholder : 'Select'}
            closeOnSelect={props.closeOnSelect}
            clearable={props.clearable}
            searchable={props.searchable}
            options={props.options ? props.options : []}
            value={props.simpleValue ? props.options.filter(
                ({ value }) => value === props.value) : props.value}
            isLoading={props.isLoading}
            className={` ${props.className ? props.className : ''}`}
            onChange={option => props.onChange(props.property, props.simpleValue ? option?.value : option)}
            onBlur={props.onBlur}/>
        {props.error && <FormHelperText style={{ color: '#f44336' }}>{props.error}</FormHelperText>}
    </div>
);
```

because of being sticky, the header of the table component is now corrupting the view of the drop downs

currently, I am getting,
[image]

the expected behavior is,
[image]

kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this overlapping is because mui table's sticky header's default `z-index` value is `2` and is greater than `react-select` menu's default `z-index` value `1`.

So, you need to increase `z-index` of `react-select` component's menu property to some value that is greater than 2 like this:

```
const customStyles = {
    menu: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      zIndex: 3
    })
};


<ReactSelect
  value={selectedOption}
  onChange={setSelectedOption}
  options={options}
  styles={customStyles}
/>
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-table-qs5txx?file=/demo.tsx) for a live working example of this usage.